# Google Sheets - Count Total Number of True and False answers in same column, different workbook

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to figure out how to count the total number of all the Yes's and No's together, that are drop-down options in column H... which lives in another sheet. I want the formula to add the yes and no responses and use that total in a master sheet.

So far, I've tried the following formula, but I get a Formula Parse Error:

=COUNTIFS(IMPORTRANGE("url", "Answers 2023!H:H"), “No”)
+COUNTIFS(IMPORTRANGE("url", "Answers 2023!H:H"), “Yes”)

I even tried it as an array. FYI....Google Sheets keeps adding this to the end, I delete it, Sheets adds it back: "))))))

=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(IMPORTRANGE("url", "Answers 2023!H:H"=“No”,
IF(IMPORTRANGE("url", "Answers 2023!H:H"="Yes”))))))"))))))

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `QUERY()` function with `matches` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue could be with the quotes used for `yes` and `no` part in the formula.

Can you try:

```
=COUNTIF(IMPORTRANGE("Sheet_ID", "'Answers 2023'!H:H"), "No") 
+
COUNTIF(IMPORTRANGE("Sheet_ID", "'Answers 2023'!H:H"), "Yes")
```